# AngularJS switch path when user scroll

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, scroll

I try to detect when the user scroll the view and then I would like to switch view.

I'm using a directive for detect when the user scroll :

```
.directive("scroll", function ($window) {
return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
        if (this.pageYOffset >= 1) {
            scope.boolChangeClass = true;
            console.log('Scrolled down');
        } else {
            scope.boolChangeClass = false;
            console.log('Scroll up');
        }
        scope.$apply();
    });
};
```

The directive is called on the div with the ng-controller

```
<div scroll ng-controller="MyCtrl1">
```

I get the boolChangeClass in the view of Controller 1

```
   <span>{{boolChangeClass}}</span>
```

And log the result in my controller

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl1', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, http) {
   console.log($scope.boolChangeClass);
}]);
```

How can I detect in my controller that boolChangeClass have changed and then I would like to go to controller2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$watch` to detect any change in the scope variable.

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl1', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, http) {
   console.log($scope.boolChangeClass);

   $scope.$watch(function(){
       return $scope.boolChangeClass;
   }. function() {
      console.log($scope.boolChangeClass); // will be called when the values gets changed
   })

}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is where you should use services to share data among different controllers..

Or if you really want to do in simple, just define a baseController in upper root div and define your boolChaneClass in that baseController so its accessible from both child controllers (ctrl1, ctrl2 ...)